# Style a React component based on its ID

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-dnd

So i've written a simple TODO with drag and drop and add, all the cards are generated using a function , my second column has an id to it and I now want any task added or dragged to it to have a css line through. How would I go about targeting it using the id
`<div class="listContainer" id="y0zitt47gfb">`

My code:
P.S Does not use create-react-app , just brought in through CDN and also uses react-dnd

```
let { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } = window.ReactBeautifulDnd;

let lists = {};

let storeLists = () => {
  console.log("Writing Lists to Storage");
  console.log(lists);
  window.localStorage.setItem("listStore", JSON.stringify(lists));
  console.log("Set Correctly");
  lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listStore"));
};

class Task extends React.Component {
  deleteTask = () => {
    let listId = this.props.listId;
    let index = lists[listId]["tasks"].findIndex((task) => {
      return task["taskId"] == this.props.inputTask["taskId"];
    });
    lists[this.props.listId]["tasks"].splice(index, 1);
    storeLists();
    this.props.refresh();
  };

  taskContentChanged = (event) => {
    let listId = this.props.listId;
    console.log(listId);
    console.log(lists[listId]);
    console.log(this.props.inputTask);
    let index = lists[listId]["tasks"].findIndex((task) => {
      return task["taskId"] == this.props.inputTask["taskId"];
    });
    console.log(index);
    lists[listId]["tasks"][index]["taskDescription"] = event.target.innerText;
  };

  keyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target.className == "taskCardContent") {
      storeLists();
      event.target.blur();
      this.props.refresh();
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Draggable
        draggableId={this.props.inputTask["taskId"]}
        index={this.props.index}
      >
        {(provided) => {
          return (
            <div
              class="taskCard"
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              id={this.props.inputTask["id"]}
            >
              <p
                onKeyDown={this.keyPress}
                onInput={this.taskContentChanged}
                contentEditable="true"
                class="taskCardContent"
              >
                {" "}
                {this.props.inputTask["taskDescription"]}{" "}
              </p>
              <img
                onClick={this.deleteTask}
                class="deleteTaskIcon"
                src="assets/delete.svg"
                alt="Delete Task"
              />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Draggable>
    );
  };
}

class List extends React.Component {
  addTask = () => {
    let listId = this.props.inputList['listId'];
  
    let newTaskInput = document.getElementById(listId + "Input");

    if (newTaskInput.value != "") {
      let newTask = {
        taskId: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15),
        taskDescription: newTaskInput.value,
      };
      lists[listId]["tasks"].push(newTask);
      storeLists();
    }

    newTaskInput.value = "";
    this.props.refresh();
  };

  deleteList = () => {
    let listId = this.props.inputList["listId"];
    lists[listId] = undefined;
    storeLists();
    this.props.refresh();
  };

  listNameChanged = (event) => {
    let listId = this.props.inputList["listId"];
    lists[listId]["listName"] = event.target.innerText;
  };

  keyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.target.className == "newListItemInput" && event.key == "Enter") {
      this.addTask();
    }
    if (event.target.className == "listName" && event.key == "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.target.blur();
      storeLists();
      this.props.refresh();
    }
  };

  render = () => {
    let list = this.props.inputList;

    return (
      <div class="body">
        <div class="newListItem">
          <input
            onKeyDown={this.keyPress}
            id={list["listId"] + "Input"}
            type="text"
            class="newListItemInput"
            placeholder="Add To List"
          />
          <img
            class="addTaskIcon"
            onClick={this.addTask}
            src="assets/submit.svg"
            alt="Add Task"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="listContainer" id={this.props.id}>
          <div class="listHeader">
            <h4 class="listName">{list["listName"]} </h4>
          </div>
          <Droppable droppableId={list["listId"]}>
            {(provided) => {
              return (
                <div
                  class="taskList"
                  {...provided.droppableProps}
                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                >
                  {Object.values(list["tasks"]).map((task, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Task
                        index={index}
                        inputTask={task}
                        listId={list["listId"]}
                        refresh={this.props.refresh}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </Droppable>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appLists: lists,
  };

  onDragEnd = (result) => {
    console.log(result);

    if (result.reason === "DROP" && result.destination) {
      let originListId = result.source.droppableId;
      let originIndex = result.source.index;
      let destinationListId = result.destination.droppableId;
      let destinationIndex = result.destination.index;

      let movedTask = lists[originListId]["tasks"][originIndex];
      lists[originListId]["tasks"].splice(originIndex, 1);
      lists[destinationListId]["tasks"].splice(destinationIndex, 0, movedTask);
    }
    storeLists();
    this.refreshApp();
  };

  refreshApp = () => {
    console.log("Refreshing...");
    this.setState({
      appLists: lists,
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
          {Object.values(this.state.appLists).map((list) => {
            return (
              <List
                id={list["listId"]}
                inputList={list}
                refresh={this.refreshApp}
              />
            );
          })}
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

let startUp = () => {
  if (
    localStorage.getItem("listStore") &&
    !["undefined", "null"].includes(localStorage.getItem("listStore"))
  ) {
    lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listStore"));
  } else {
    console.log("Creating List in Storage");
    lists = {
      f0ziqq7gfn: {
        listId: "f0ziqq7gfn",
        listName: "To Do",
        tasks: [
          { taskId: "fk8vs85v0wh", taskDescription: "Watch Regular Show" },
          { taskId: "kd3ve56f5fh", taskDescription: "" },
        ],
      },

      y0zitt47gfb: {
        listId: "y0zitt47gfb",
        listName: "Complete",
        tasks: [
          { taskId: "v0zigt47whc", taskDescription: "Create React Todo" },
          { taskId: "b0zi5t4rwhc", taskDescription: "Somehow get a PS5" },
        ],
      },
    };
    storeLists();
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
};

startUp();
```

Comment: Brainfart moment, just used that ID standardly , BURN OUT

Answer (score 0):

Brainfart moment, just used that ID standardly , BURN OUT